# Latest from each x in django

Tags: python, django

I have 2 tables in my db:

```
Category (
  Id
  Name)

Post (
  Id
  Name
  Content
  Category (PK))
```

I need to get the latest post from each category into a html-table. I've tried to slice the object in the view file, with `[:1]`, but then I only get the latest post. I've also tried to slice the for-loop in the template file, but that doesn't work either. The problem is that if the two latest post are from the same category they will be shown and I just want the very latest from each category. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from my_project.models import Category

def my_view(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all().select_related(depth=1)
    return render(request, 'your_template.html', {'categories' : categories})

#your_template.html
<table>
    {% for c in categories %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ c.post_set.all|slice:":1" }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

You'll need to add a date/datetime field and order your posts on that to do your ordering.

Comment: Hi. I created a working sample application for you using SQLite: http://btaylorweb.com/static/transfer/example.tar.gz. There's just one view and template that will show one post object per category in a table.

Comment: Just wanted to follow up with you and see if that application worked...?